# UITableView footerview is changing group table style

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a grouped table I am trying to add a footerview to.  However when I execute my code it adds a grey bar between every section and changes the visual style from a grouped table look to a normal UITableView.

How can I keep footerview from adding between every section?  Here is my code (in the init method)

```
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,500)];
    SubmitButton *submitButton;
    submitButton = [[SubmitButton alloc] init];
    [submitButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_TITLE_SEARCH", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    submitButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,10,self.tableView.frame.size.width,50);
    submitButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [footerView addSubview:submitButton];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the section number in the delegate method to figure out if this is indeed the last section

```
   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section; 
    {
          if (section == 5){
                format section.....
          } else {
             return nil;
          }
    }
```

I'm using the number 5 as an example for the last section of your table.  You'll also need to set the height for the other sections to 0 if you don't want the offset

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
       if (section == 5) {
          return 100;
       } else {
          return 0;
       }
 }
```

Comment: Actually,this is kind of the solution, but the problem still persists that im getting footers added for each section (which should not be happening) and i do not want that.  I want to add a view to the actual table footer, not the section footers.

Comment: I take it you want this footer in the scrollable area?  If so what's the difference between adding this as the last section's footer?  This is what Apple provides for you.

If you're trying to make it OUTSIDE of the scrollable area (and the table cells scroll underneath it) - you would just throw another view onto the view controller and align it with the UITableView

Not too sure why you're getting footers everywhere though - can you post some more code?

Comment: Actually I want it in the non-scrollable area.  I found out however that the regardless if its a sectionfooter or a tableFooterView, they all scroll with the table.  So i'm having to programmatically create my table with a shorter frame, and add a view with a button at the bottom. (if I put the button view on top of the table rows are hidden under the button which is not OK)  Also, the bars that were appearing between each row were actually headers.  They were appearing when the groupStyle was being lost.

Comment: Yup that's exactly the right way to do it.  UITableView is actually a subclass of UIScrollView, so all of it's contents will scroll.  There's a little magic in there with section headers being somewhat sticky, but otherwise you're not going to get anything to stay in one spot.

Comment: is there a way to .. extend the graphics of the table without actually extending the view itself?  ive found I have a large black space the button is sitting in since the table stops.  I'd like to have the grey background of the table extend to the bottom.  or simulate something similar.  lightGrayColor and grayColor don't match

Comment: [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]

Comment: this is an iPad app so sadly, that doesn't work ive found.  no easy solution it seems.  Thanks for the help though Sean